# useEffect in React js not being called

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I am trying to fetch an api using `useEffect`, but the `useEffect` is not called. The console.log inside `useEffect` is not consoled.

```
import React from 'react';
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';
import Pagination from '@mui/material/Pagination';
import axios from "axios";
const mixers = [
  {
    id:1,
    img: "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/51a5GWUyz5L._SX679_.jpg",
    title: "Wonderchef Vietri 500 Watt Mixer Grinder"
  },
  {
    id:2,
    img: "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41gZhEcCCQL._SX300_SY300_QL70_FMwebp_.jpg",
    title: "Wonderchef Nutriblend 400W Mixer "
  },
  {
    id:3,
    img: "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41zr2i4M3FL._SX300_SY300_QL70_FMwebp_.jpg",
   title: "Prestige Deluxe VS 750W Mixer Grinder"
  },
  {
    id:4,
    img: "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/41MJtzx-VbL._SX300_SY300_QL70_FMwebp_.jpg",
    title: "Prestige Nakshatra Plus 750W Mixer Grinder"
  },
 {
    id:5,
    img: "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/31AnEQz5zUS._SY300_SX300_QL70_FMwebp_.jpg",
    title: "Prestige Stylo V2 750W Mixer Grinder"
  },
  {
    id:6,
    img: "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/31kH2o3mGxS._SX300_SY300_QL70_FMwebp_.jpg",
    title: "Orpat Mixer Grinder Kitchen Majestic"
  },
  {
    id:7,
    img: "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/31e+LYu9HSL._SY300_SX300_.jpg",
    title: "Lifelong llcmb02 500W Mixer Grinder"
  },
 {
    id:8,
    img: "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/31uDJciyJdL._SX300_SY300_QL70_FMwebp_.jpg",
    title: "Florita Vinca 450W Mixer Grinder"
  },
  {
    id:9,
    img: "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/31RW094g6ZL._SX300_SY300_QL70_FMwebp_.jpg",
    title: "Florita Pine 500W Mixer Grinder"
 },
  {
    id:10,
   img: "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/418Gt0kIInL._SX300_SY300_QL70_FMwebp_.jpg",
   title: "Pringle Real Juicer Mixer Grinder"
 }
];
function App() {
  const [show, setShow]= useState(true);
  const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState(null);
  const [search, setSearch]= useState("");
  const [active, setActive]= useState("ProductList");

return (
    <><><><div className="navbar">

      <h1 className="main-heading">SHOPPING ASSISTANT</h1>
      <h3>Department: Electronics Items(Mixers)</h3>
</><div className="data-container">
    <div className="mixer-list-container">
{mixers.map((mxr) => (

            <div className="mixer-container">
              <Mixer mixers={mxr} />
              <button className="button-view-details"
                onClick={() => {
                  setActiveIndex(mxr.id);
                  if (activeIndex === mxr.id) {
                    setShow(!show);
                  }
                } }>
                View Details
              </button>
              {show && (activeIndex === mxr.id) ? <MixerDetails id={mxr.id} /> : null}

            </div>
          ))}
          </div>
        </div>

    </><div className='footer'>
        <Pagination count={1} variant="outlined" shape="rounded" />
      </div></>
  
  );
}

function Mixer({mixers}){
  
    return(
      <div>
       
        <img src={mixers.img} alt={mixers.title} className="mixer-picture" />
        <h2 className="mixer-name">{mixers.title}</h2>
      </div>
    );
  }

  function MixerDetails({id}){
   const [snapdeal_data, setSnapdeal_data]= useState([]);
   const [amazon_data, setAmazon_data]= useState([])
   console.log("above useeffect");
   useEffect(()=> {
      console.log("useeffect called");
      fetch(`${API}/amzn_data_db`)
          .then((data)=>data.json())
          .then((amzn)=>setAmazon_data(amzn));
 },[]);
useEffect(()=>{
      fetch(`${API}/snpdl_data_db`)
          .then((data)=>data.json())
          .then((snpdl)=>setSnapdeal_data(snpdl));
    },[]);
 const  id1=id-1;
    return(
        <>
        <div>
        <h4>Product Details</h4>
        <div className="data-container">
          <table className='data-table'>
            <thead><tr>
              <th>Website</th>
              <th>Amazon</th>
              <th>Snapdeal</th>
              </tr></thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
              <th>Price</th>
              <td>{amazon_data[id1].price}</td>
              <td>{snapdeal_data[id1].price}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Offer Price</th>
              <td>{amazon_data[id1].offer_price}</td>
              <td>{snapdeal_data[id1].offer_price}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>Rating</th>
              <td>{amazon_data[id1].rating}</td>
              <td>{snapdeal_data[id1].rating}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <th>URL</th>
              <td><a href={amazon_data[id1].url} target="_blank">Amazon Link</a></td>
              <td><a href={snapdeal_data[id1].url} target="_blank">Snapdeal Link</a></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div></>  
      );
  } 
  

export default App;
```

I am trying to fetch data from a database using nodejs as backend.

The console is:

above useeffect
above useeffect

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading
> 'price')

I also tried async await and axios.get instead of fetch, but still same result.

Comment: can you please post your entire code?

Comment: I have posted the entire code. The API refers to data from mongodb fetched using nodejs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, please provide complete code and line from which you are getting `reading price from undefined` error.

Having said that, here are a few things you should take care of

- Make sure you have supplied proper dependency array to your `useEffect` hook
- Make sure you are using null safety → use `data?.price` in place of `data.price`

`useEffect` is not executed because your component is not yet rendered. Error is thrown from your JSX.

Try this

```
....
const  id1=id-1;
if(!amazon_data[id1]) return <h1>Loading...</h1>

return (...)
```

Comment: I have updated the entire code.

Comment: replace all `amazon_data[id1].` by `amazon_data[id1]?.`. Your `useEffect` will be called once the component is rendered.

Comment: It worked. The useEffect was called. I am new to react so can you please explain why we are adding "?" and how it worked.